# what will get affected if hibernate version is upgraded

Tags: java, hibernate, jonas

Should we upgrade tomcat and jonas version if we upgrade hibernate version from 3.1.3 to 3.3?

and what all jars to be included if we upgrade the hibernate version from 3.1.3 to 3.3?

and also will it affect the JDk?

FYI:we are using db oracle11g and we use dialect10g for connection.

Answer (score 0):

One checkpoint I can see is -upgrading may have effect on package changes of some classes of Hibernate framework, but it's a possibility. Also, to know what jars will be included in this version upgrade, you can refer to both the releases and see what are new jars. Also, will depend on what JDK is currently being used. This is a very generalized question and would require efforts from your side.

Comment: currently we are using JDK1.5